# What gives Hyperledger fabric a ssl legitimacy error when I use -k/--insecure?

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to install the binaries for Hyperledger fabric but I run into an error.

```
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I do know this means i need to put -k or --insecure in the curl statment. However I am doing so and it doesn't work.

```
 curl --insecure -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 2.3.0 1.4.9
```

when I run this the first half is fine, the hyperledger/fabric-samples repo clone will succeed.

Here is the entire output

```
\Clone hyperledger/fabric-samples repo

===> Cloning hyperledger/fabric-samples repo
Cloning into 'fabric-samples'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 20, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
remote: Total 7386 (delta 2), reused 8 (delta 0), pack-reused 7366
Receiving objects: 100% (7386/7386), 4.26 MiB | 905.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3823/3823), done.
===> Checking out v2.3.0 of hyperledger/fabric-samples

Pull Hyperledger Fabric binaries

===> Downloading version 2.3.0 platform specific fabric binaries
===> Downloading:  https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/releases/download/v2.3.0/hyperledger-fabric-windows-amd64-2.3.0.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
==> There was an error downloading the binary file.

------> 2.3.0 platform specific fabric binary is not available to download <----
```

I am still a student so it could easily be a stupid problem, but I'm really stuck. So please can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was -k/--insecure was not good enough i had to change it for all connections with :

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```